# `new lru.prototype.lrunode(key, value);` expression

Tags: javascript

I was reading this blog https://chrisrng.svbtle.com/lru-cache-in-javascript and haven't seen this usage before:

`var node = new lru.prototype.lrunode(key, value);`

why would you use this instead of just saying `var node = this.lrunode` inside the `get` function?

Is this code expression "legal"? I find it confusing. The code works, but I wonder the consequences of using `new` invoked with `prototype`

Comment: `new` does not care where the function came from. There is nothing special in retrieving a reference to a function from a property named `prototype`.

Comment: so is there a difference in `var node = new lru.prototype.lrunode(key, value);` and `var node = this.lrunode(key,value);`? if there is, what is it?

Comment: In general case - there is difference, in this particular code (if the callee does not monkey-patch `lru`) - I don't think it would be different. PS: it would be `node = new this.lrunode(key,value);`